# Layout grid items in css

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, responsive

I just want to know what's the best way to layout the items so that I could have the same result shown in the attachment or what's the trick behind that.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it a requirement that the top right image is shown just slightly smaller than the other two? (are those dotted red lines significant in indicating this?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find CSS Grid to be the most intuitive for this type of x/y directional layout. Using [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) is a fun way to approach layout since you can essentially create any layout you'd like and then assign classes to the arbitrary names you've used for your grid areas. The dots (`.`) mean that the grid area is empty.

Although this is totally possible to accomplish using `flex`, the additional markup needed is undesirable. I would argue that any layout requiring control over both x and y axis is more intuitive and scalable using `grid`.

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  gap: 0.75rem;
  grid-template-areas:
                       ". item2"
                       ". item2"
                       "item1 item2"
                       "item1 item2"
                       "item1 item3"
                       "item1 item3"
                       ". item3"                       
                       ". item3";                       
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  color: ghostwhite;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">item 1</div>
  <div class="item item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="item item3">item 3</div>  
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1sv4geo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can inspire from below code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap:8px;
}

.container .item {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}

.inner-item {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner-item">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner-item">
    
    </div>
    <div class="inner-item">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice simple layout, and may well be good enough, but is not the same as the layout in the question.

Comment: @AHaworth  yes but I write that he can Inspire from my example not just copy that :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS grid gives you a lot of control in a two dimensional space.

We need the relative dimensions of the 3 grid items.

Measuring up the given layout I found the width of the first image to be 7cm, to second (top) image 6cm and the bottom right image 6.5cm. And they are square.

grid works in columns and rows so we need to find a suitable column width. (7 + 6.5) = 13.5 so multiply by 2 to give a number of columns and the grid items will fill 14, 12, 13 columns respectively.

So to get this:

[image]

we can do:

```css
.pics {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(27, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(27, 1fr);
  gap: 2vmin;
  width: 50vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.pics>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2vmin;
}

.pics>*:nth-child(1) {
  background: magenta;
  grid-column: 1 / span 14;
  grid-row: 5 / span 14;
}

.pics>*:nth-child(2) {
  background: cyan;
  grid-column: 15 / span 12;
  grid-row: 1 / span 12;
}

.pics>*:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 15 / span 13;
  grid-row: 13 / span 13;
}
```

```html
<div class="pics">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```